# updateQuery of fetchMore function in apollo react hooks doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: javascript, react-native, graphql, react-apollo

I am in the middle of learning how to use React right now and doing course on [fullstackopen.com](https://fullstackopen.com) (in chapter 10 precisely). I'm in the middle of building a phone app that fetch list of repositories data from server(already provided by the course) and right now implementing cursor-based infinite scrolling with apollo. This is what my code looks like:

```
const useRepositories = (variables) => {
  const [fetchRepositories, { data, loading, fetchMore }] = useLazyQuery(GET_REPOSITORIES_WITH_ARGUMENT, {
    variables,
  });
  const [repositories, setRepositories] = useState();
// ...


const handleFetchMore = async () => {
    const canFetchMore = !loading && data && data.repositories.pageInfo.hasNextPage;
    if(!canFetchMore){
      return;
    }
    //setIsRepoFromFetchMore('in preparation');
    await fetchMore({
      query: GET_REPOSITORIES_WITH_ARGUMENTS,
      variables: {
        after: data.repositories.pageInfo.endCursor,
        searchKeyword: searchbar,
        ...variables,
        ...variableInUse.value,
      },
      updateQuery: (previousResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => { // I don't know why, but i can't find where update query put the resulting variable
        const nextResult = {
          repositories: {
            ...fetchMoreResult.repositories
          },
          edges: [
            ...previousResult.repositories.edges,
            ...fetchMoreResult.repositories.edges
          ],
        };
        return nextResult;
      }
    });
    //setIsRepoFromFetchMore('true');
  };

useEffect(() => {
    if(data && !loading){
      setRepositories(data.repositories.edges.map(edge => edge.node));
    }
  }, [data, loading]);
```

and this is how i use the custom hooks and call the fetchMore function:

```
const RepositoryList = () => {
  const { repositories, lazyRepositories, fetchMore, searchBarObject } = useRepositories({
    first: 8
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    lazyRepositories();
  }, []);

  return(<RepositoryListContainer repositories={repositories} lazyRepositories={lazyRepositories} fetchMore={fetchMore} searchBarObject={searchBarObject}/>);
};

export const RepositoryListContainer = ({ 
  repositories, 
  lazyRepositories, 
  fetchMore, 
  searchBarObject 
}) => {
   // ...
  const RepositoryList = repositories;
  const handleOnEndReached =  () => fetchMore();

  return(
    <FlatList 
      data={RepositoryList}
      ListHeaderComponent={<RepositoryHeader lazyRepositories={lazyRepositories} searchBarObject={searchBarObject}/>}
      onEndReached={handleOnEndReached}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
      // ...
    />
  );
};
```

Now this is what my exact problem is:

```
await fetchMore({
      query: GET_REPOSITORIES_WITH_ARGUMENTS,
      variables: {
        after: data.repositories.pageInfo.endCursor,
        searchKeyword: searchbar,
        ...variables,
        ...variableInUse.value,
      },
      updateQuery: (previousResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
        const nextResult = {
          repositories: {
            ...fetchMoreResult.repositories
          },
          edges: [
            ...previousResult.repositories.edges,
            ...fetchMoreResult.repositories.edges
          ],
        };
        return nextResult;
      }
    });
```

when fetchMore is called, the function in updateQuery property run just fine except that i have no way to access the returning value of updateQuery. The data in "data" variable from useLazyQuery is the new data fetched from the server and not the merged data of the old and the new data. And the returned value of the fetchMore function itself is the same data in "data" variable.

I could just merge both data manually, but then when i recall the query it will only return the new data since the cache itself doesn't get updated with the merged data, and i'd rather not mess with the cache myself if i don't have to. So my option is limited to using "network-and-cache" for my fetch-policy.

I've been searching around for the answer around but most of the people that has this problem doesn't get their question answered and some that do use a lot of function that has been deprecated, or just really different from what i'm using right now.

And if you want to check the module i was talking about here is the exact link:
https://fullstackopen.com/en/part10/testing_and_extending_our_application#infinite-scrolling

It has the supposedly working code.
Thanks for your help in advance.